# Quel serait un terme décrivant le fait que quelqu’un parle d’entrée de jeu d’une révélation pour attirer l’attention sans y donner de suite?

Tags: expressions, usage, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, reformulation

Quel serait un terme ou quelle serait une expression décrivant le fait que quelqu’un parle en introduction d’un événement qu’il aurait soi-disant vécu (qui est sûrement faux) sans y revenir par la suite juste pour accrocher ses interlocuteurs; un propos qui ne sera pas suivi d’effet pour susciter l’intérêt général à la manière d’une scène dramatique.

J’ai entendu récemment « c’était juste pour la mise en scène », en renvoyant à un propos - dans une série télévisée- qui était dit d’emblée pour produire une forte impression mais qui ne sera suivi d’aucun effet, c’est-à-dire une révélation sur laquelle le comédien ne reviendra point par la suite. (Révélation qui tourne court, qui se révélera creuse)

J’avais en tête « pétard mouillé », mais elle se dit d’une révélation qui n’a pas l’effet escompté alors que dans la situation que je cherche à décrire, il s’agit juste d’une révélation que l’on pourrait dire fausse pour tenir en haleine des auditeurs. Pourrait-on parler d’une manipulation dramatique?

Edit 1

Mascarade?

Edit 2

Duperie?

Edit 3

Hypocrisie?

Edit 4

Feinte?

Edit 5

Imposture?

Edit 6

Artifice de mise en scène?

Edit 7

Illusion scénique?

Édit 8

Effet scénique?

Comment: Diverses expressions peuvent convenir, mais sur quel aspect voulez-vous insister en priorité ? Le fait d'éblouir le public ? Le mensonge ? La désinvolture face au risque de se faire démasquer par la suite ? Je ne pense pas qu'une seule formule puisse recouvrir tout cela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fanfaronnade ; effet d'annonce ; esbroufe ; pour faire le beau ; faire l'intéressant ; pour se rendre intéressant ; affabulation.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que vous cherchez l'équivalent de l'expression anglaise *red herring* :

> C'est une diversion.
> C'est pour brouiller les pistes.

Comment: red herring n'est pas dit en "introduction"

Answer (score 0):

C'est le plus souvent une **vantardise**.